# Find and Replace Operation Using Regex with Inner Function Not Working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new on Stack Overflow and I am hoping someone can please help me with the following code.

I am trying to adapt a piece of code from the Ascher, Ravenscroft, and Martelli Python Cookbook. I would like to replace all words in `Text` containing a 'long-s' with the equivalent word spelled with a modern lowercase s using dictionary key:value pairs (all text is utf-8). I am able to build the dictionaries from existing tab-separated files without a problem (I am using a simple sample dictionary in the code for ease of editing), however I would like to complete all the changes in a single pass for speed and efficiency.  I have removed the `map` and `escape` parts of the code as I don't think the 'long-s' needs escaping (I could be wrong though!). The first section works fine, however the inner function `one_xlat` seems not to do anything.  It does not return/print `Text` at the end, and there is no error message. I have run the code in the command line and IDLE with the same result.  I have run the code with and without using `map` and `escape`, and I have renamed the variables just to be sure, but I cannot quite make it work. Would someone please be able to help?  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious and thank you very much in advance.

Original Code from Ascher, Ravenscroft, and Martelli:

```
import re
def multiple_replace(text, adict):
    rx = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, adict)))
    def one_xlat(match):
        return adict[match.group(0)]
    return rx.sub(one_xlat, text)
```

The adapted version:

```
import re

adictCR = {"handſome":"handsome","ſeated":"seated","veſſels":"vessels","ſea-side":"sea-side","ſand":"sand","waſhed":"washed", "oſ":"of", "proſpect":"prospect"}
text = "The caſtle, which is very extenſive, contains a ſtrong building, formerly uſed by the late emperor as his principal treaſury, and a noble terrace, which commands an extensive proſpect oſ the town of Sallee, the ocean, and all the neighbouring country."

def word_replace(text, adictCR):
    regex_dict = re.compile('|'.join(adictCR))
    print(regex_dict)
    def one_xlat(match):
        return adictCR[match.group(0)]
    return regex_dict.sub(one_xlat, text)
    print(text)

word_replace(text, adictCR)
```

Comment: Looks to me like you have changed the variable name from rx to regex_dict but then still used rx further on.

Comment: It is likely easier also to just use the dict itself for the replacement. There is not advantage to a regex here.

Comment: MandyShaw - thanks very much for pointing out the error. I have corrected this, but the problem remains.

Comment: And dawg - thanks for the reply.  I wish to use a regex as I understand it will enable the replacement operation to happen in one pass, rather than using `replace` which would result in multiple copies of the text being created.  Do I have this correct?  Apologies if I do not!  Ultimately, the code will be used to process thousands of pages with very large dictionaries, so I am trying to keep efficiency a priority.  Hope that makes sense!  Thanks again.

Comment: [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) takes an optional count for replacements. That would be monumentally faster if this is your goal. Do something like 1) Loop the text word for word; 2) check word in dict; 3) replace word if found in dict; 4) profit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your code this way:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

adictCR = {"handſome":"handsome","ſeated":"seated","veſſels":"vessels","ſea-side":"sea-side","ſand":"sand","waſhed":"washed", "oſ":"of", "proſpect":"prospect"}
text = "The caſtle, which is very extenſive, contains a ſtrong building, formerly uſed by the late emperor as his principal treaſury, and a noble terrace, which commands an extensive proſpect oſ the town of Sallee, the ocean, and all the neighbouring country."

new_s=[]        
for g in (m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'\w+|\W+', text)):
    if g in adictCR:
        g=adictCR[g]
    new_s.append(g)
```

Then you can get your new string with `''.join(new_s)`.

Note: the pattern `'\w+|\W+'` only works in recent versions (3.1+) of Python with non-ascii text. You can also do `split(r'(\W)', str)` as an alternate, but I don't think that will work on Python 2 with utf-8.

Comment: Dawg - thanks very much for the help.  I'm using Python 3.7 so your suggestion works well.  I appreciate you taking the time to help.